# Reading an image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file, imread

I want to load an image in MATLAB :

```
f=imread('fulldirectory');
m=size(f);
printf('m');
```

MATLAB shows me this error when I attempt to run it:

```
"Error using imread (line 349)"
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Well, `fulldirectory` must not be an image file

Comment: I assume that fulldirectory is a variable. Then you should not use quotation mark. It is the same for 3. line .

Comment: then it must be what ?

Comment: You should add some context to the question that makes it clear what `fulldirectory` is.

Answer (score 0):

Imread function needs a file format, e.g., jpg.

You can use one of the following MATLAB codes.

```
f = imread('ngc6543a.jpg'); 
f = imread('ngc6543a', 'jpg');
```

Also, just omit the semicolon (;) from your second line of your codes, if you want to know the dimension of the image. MATLAB will display the size of the image.

```
m=size(f)
```

MATLAB has some test images such as ngc6543a.jpg and you can try my code in your MATLAB.